# Using source command automatically when I open a terminal

Tags: terminal

I regularly use the command SOURCE to be able to open a software. So I type :

source /usr/blabla/blabla

softwarelaunch

I wonder if it is possible to call the source command everytime I launch a terminal. So I would only have to launch et terminal and to type softwarelaunch.

Comment: depends on your shell... could put it into .cshrc, .tcshr, .bashrc, etc... whatever your shell's local rc file is.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the file `~/.bashrc` is for!

This file gets `source`d every time you open a terminal window. If you want to execute `/usr/bla/bla` then you can add a line at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source /usr/bla/bla
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/foo/bar ]; then
   . /usr/local/foo/bar
fi
```